# "Attempted to assign to readonly property" when trying to use context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use React's Context API on a React Native app, but I keep getting an error whenever I try to use a context provider. I can't figure out what the error says.

I have the following code:

```
// PlayerContext.ts
import React from "react";

export const PlayerContext = React.createContext(222);

// PlayerContextProvider.tsx
import React from "react";
import { PlayerContext } from "./PlayerContext";

export default class PlayerContextProvider extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <PlayerContext.Provider value={222}>
        {this.props.children}
      </PlayerContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

//HomePage.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import PlayerContextProvider from "./Player/PlayerContextProvider";

export default class HomePage extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <PlayerContextProvider>
        <Text>test</Text>
      </PlayerContextProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

When trying to run the app I get this error:

```
Attempted to assign to readonly property.
popProvider
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12077:12
unwindWork
[...]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This much code doesnt seem to have a problem.

Comment: Same issue here...

Comment: 'fixed' it by reverting react back to 16.3 :-/